# 'Mesh' object has no attribute 'faces'

Tags: python, export, add-on

I'm trying to do an export plugin for Blender 2.69 to metasequoia file (.mqo).

Vertex is exported but i have some trouble with faces.

I used [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Multi-File_packages#Simple_obj_exporter) has a reference but it's for blender 2.5 so i think it's outdated.

[image: error]

[source code](https://github.com/50thomatoes50/blender.io_mqo/blob/master/io_scene_mqo/export_mqo.py)

Answer (score 8):

Faces are now accessible in [`Mesh.polygons`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons). But seeing that your reference is so outdated, there may be other deprecated API usage in your script. So far, [this link](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) is always redirected to the latest Blender Python API manual, you may want to refer to it instead.

Comment: faces = me.faces --->  faces = me.polygons

Comment: The following page has a few examples that some people may have.  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes

Comment: You might be able to fix it by simply replacing `.faces` by `.tessfaces` and a call to calculate the tessfaces: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/info_gotcha.html#upgrading-exporters-from-2-62