# bpy.ops.object.select_inverse() removed from Python API?

Tags: python, scripting

A script I wrote, which used to work (I think Blender 2.6), no longer seems to work. I think the `select_inverse()` operator has been removed?!

I made the mistake of removing the old version of Blender before installing 2.7, so I can't look back at old module.

Wow, go away for year and try to come back, everything is changed and old Blender forums are gone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select_inverse()` was available up to 2.61 ([API docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_61_release/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.select_inverse)), it's missing in docs from 2.62 on.

The following operator inverts the current object selection and should be equivalent:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='INVERT')
```

You can get every past release here:
http://download.blender.org/release/

Blender.org forums were meant for developers, and the user community was mostly active on http://blenderartists.org/ anyway. Consider BA.org the successor to the official forums.

Comment: Thanx CoDEmanX I remember you from old forum, you continue to be most helpful !

Comment: Next challenge is: bpy.data.meshes[].faces already answered in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/export-api-mesh-object-has-no-attribute-faces   looking at Blender change logs I see "faces" mentioned in http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_71_release/change_log.html but not select_inverse and did not see anything in /Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes wondering if there is a consolidated change log somewhere for all versions

Comment: The mesh system changed in 2.63 to allow for Ngons and was auto-added to the change log. The API changes page is something I created and isn't really maintained by anyone. Chances are that neither of the resources point out API changes, such as the removal of an operator. You need to figure that out yourself and maybe subscribe to the developers mailing list.